# Proof that $X = \left\{ A \in \mathbb R^{6,5} : V \subset \ker(A) \right\}$ is linear subspace and find its $\dim$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Proof that if $\dim V = 3 $ then $X = \left\{ A \in \mathbb R^{6,5} : V  \subset  ker(A) \right\}$ is linear subspace and find its $\dim$

## What I've done

I think that I have done proof.
$ \forall \vec{v} \in V. A\vec{v} = 0 $ and $B\vec{v}=0$
but from property of the matrix product it follows that: 
$$ A\vec{v} + B\vec{v} = (A+B)\vec{v} $$

Moreover if $A\vec{x}=0$ then $(\alpha A)\vec{x} =0$ and in to other side too. So ok.

## My problem

But how in use of given informations find its dimension? My scribbles do not lead to anything.

Comment: What do you denote $\Bbb R^{6,5}$?

Comment: Sorry, I used to write `\RR` but there it does not work I didn't know how to write it. But now I will remember, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb R^{6,5}$ is a linear space of dimension $6 \times 5=30$.

If $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ (with $v_i \in \mathbb R^5$) is a basis of $V$. You have

$$X = \{A \in \mathbb R^{6,5} \ ; \ A.v_1=A.v_2=A.v_3=0\}.$$

It means that you're imposing $3 \times 6 = 18$ independent conditions in the [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) $\left(\mathbb R^{6,5}\right)^\vee$. Hence $\dim X = 30 -18=12$.

**Another proof not using the dual space**

Without loss of generality, you can suppose that $(v_1, \dots, v_5)$ is a basis of $\mathcal V = \mathbb R^5$ where $(v_1, v_2,v_3)$ is a basis of $V$. And that $(v_1^\prime, \dots, v_6^\prime)$ is a basis of $\mathcal V^\prime=\mathbb R^6$.

For $A =(a_{ij}) \in X$ expressed in those basis, you must have $$a_{11} =\dots =a_{61}=a_{12}=\dots=a_{62}=a_{13}=\dots=a_{63}=0$$ as $V \subseteq \ker A$.
If we denote $E_{ij}$ the matrix with coefficient $i,j$ equal to $1$ and the others vanishing, $(E_{14}, \dots, E_{64}, E_{15}, \dots, E_{65})$ is a basis of $X$. Proving that the dimension of that linear subspace is equal to $12$.

Comment: I don't understand this notation:  $A.v_1=A.v_2=A.v_3=0$. Does $A.v_{i} $ means $i$ column? I suspect that these are not the same vectors as the vectors from base $V$?

Comment: For a vector $v \in V$ (with 5 coordinates) $A.v$ means the image by $A$ of vector $v$. $A.v$ is a vector with 6 coordinates.

Comment: Can it be done without dual space? I haven't got this on lecture and probably I can't use that

Comment: What are the key theorems of your lecture?

Comment: image, kernel, rank, basis of linear space, sum of linear spaces linear independence and linear combinations

Comment: Another proof not using the dual space.

Comment: can you explain this step? $ a_{11} =\dots =a_{61}=a_{12}=\dots=a_{62}=a_{13}=\dots=a_{63}=0 $

Comment: $A.v_1=A.v_2=A.v_3=0$

Comment: ahh, I do not think about this time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since $V\subset\ker(A)\forall A\in X$, the rows of $A$ are orthogonal to all vectors in $V$ and thus belong to $V^\perp$, which has dimension $2$. Each row vector of $A$ is the linear combination of the two basis vectors $v_1,v_2$ of $V^\perp$.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}v_1^T+a_{12}v_2^T\\a_{21}v_1^T+a_{22}v_2^T\\\vdots\\a_{61}v_1^T+a_{62}v_2^T\end{bmatrix}=a_{11}\begin{bmatrix}v_1^T\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}+a_{12}\begin{bmatrix}v_2^T\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}+a_{21}\begin{bmatrix}0\\v_1^T\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}+...+a_{62}\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\v_2^T\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, $X$ has $12$ basis vectors.